# Can I update my passport number for the Italy visa appointment

Tags: visas, passports, italy

In the Italy visa appointment 1, I unintentionally enter the incorrect passport number. Can I change my passport's number 2? Or, can I use that appointment and have the Visa officers take care of it then?

Comment: Which appointment? Biometrics or interview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used that appointment and have the visa officers take care of it.

I have had no need to worry about it.